# Java First Applet

Tags: java, methods, applet, program-entry-point

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class sample extends Applet
{
    String chr;
    public void init()
    {
            setBackground(Color.black);
            setForeground(Color.white);
            chr="Inside init() ---->";
    }
    public void start()
    {
            chr+="Inside start() ---->";
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
            chr+="Inside paint() ---->";
            g.drawString(chr,10,0);
    }
}
```

**
This is my first applet, and as i ran this on complier..it showed an error..."main method not found...declare it as..." I dont understand the problem as i had read that applets do not require main().
**

Comment: I suggest you post the command you're using to "compile" this. `javac` (the compiler) does not look for a main method at all so will not complain. You would normally get this error if you were using `java` to attempt to run the applet as a program rather than compile it. In that case it is legitimately complaining about there being no main method.

Comment: Read [Lesson: Java Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)

Comment: 1) In 2012, use Swing (`JApplet`) 2) When at this stage of confusion about the compiler and runtime, code frame (or command-line) based apps. rather than applets.

Comment: Applets need to be run using appletviewer, not the standard java command. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989318/main-method-not-found-error-in-an-applet

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        sample x = new sample();
        x.init();
    }
```

Also the application would also run by just doing this

```
sample x = new sample();
```

It is only showing a blank applet. is that what you are trying to do?

I tried running this in eclipse.

Comment: I assume the down vote is because he's writing an applet. Applets need to be run by an applet container as there is a whole lifecycle. Simply adding a main method so the code can technically be run will not run it as an applet.

Comment: Thanku, for your help. Issue resolved. I tried to run it like a normal java program using "java sample" to run.... :D :D

Comment: @user1673045 No Problem, if my answer helped please feel free to check the best answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

A simple googling shows this

http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/JavaInDOS.html

Comment: I think your answer should be posted as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I think it's unfair to downvote this, that link does actually contain the information the OP needs to run an applet (i.e. embed in HTML page etc). However some more context in the comment would be good so he knows why you're posting a random link.

Comment: Thanku, for your help. Issue resolved. I tried to run it like a normal java program using "java sample" to run.... :D :D