# Main method not found error in an applet

Tags: java, applet, main-method

At my school I am using Notepad++ to write an applet, and I need to package it in a jar so I can sign it. I am attempting to do this with a batch file like this:

```
CD C:\Users\name\Java\bin
javac className.java
jar cvfm className.jar Manifest.txt classFolder
java -jar className.jar
PAUSE
```

And then I get a main method not found exception. There is not much I can do in terms of debugging, or opening up my jar, because as I said before, it is at school and so much of the functionality is blocked. I can provide more details if needed, thanks.

Comment: *"At my school I am using Notepad++ to write an applet,.."*  Please refer the teacher to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: I am doing this all on my own, actually. Our class uses a program called [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/), which is good for learning Java, but is very unoptimized, and starts lagging on the school's old desktops after about 300-400 LOC. The rest of the class is just doing arrays and stuff.

Comment: Was that comment directed to me?  BTW - did you pass on that message?

Comment: My teacher hasn't introduced applet to the class yet, but when he does I would gladly pass it along. The question I had is just a side project I am working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applets don't have a `main` method, so you cannot run it in the conventional way with the `java` command.

To run the applet, create an HTML file with the applet in it, and run `appletviewer` or view the page in a web browser.

Comment: You're right, I thought that by putting it into a jar as [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html) tutorial suggested, because I needed to sign it, would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't run an applet that way. It's not an application to run via the java command, and usually doesn't have a main method (unless you're writing some dual-purpose program). Run it with HTML code. The applet tutorial will show you this, and surely you've read this already.